# How to post json formatted data into a specific website using R?

Tags: json, r

First time I try to upload data in JSON format from "R" to the website but after some days spent on this one, I do not manage to make it work and see the output reflected in the website itself.

> Note: The numbers and letters provided in the example are not real

Here it is what I am doing:

1) This is the JSON format I am trying to upload/post to the server using R (which has the requested form by the website and it works as I've tried to call it directly from the internal website through an already set up button for performing this POST action).

```
 {
   "warehouseId": ["BNA5"],
   "planType": ["OP2"],
   "lineItemPlans": [
     {
       "lineItemId": ["ppr.detail.outbound.pack.chuting.medium"],
       "type": ["BaseUnitCount"],
       "values": [2]
     },
     {
       "lineItemId": ["ppr.detail.outbound.pack.chuting.medium"],
       "type": ["BaseRate"],
       "values": [0.4]
     }
   ],
   "planDates": [1516921200]
 }
```

2) This is the current code I am running to post the data (using library(httr)):

```
r <- POST("http://fclm-labor-reporting-service.integ.amazon.com/explorer/index.html", 
          body = '{
  "warehouseId": ["BNA5"],
          "planType": ["OP2"],
          "lineItemPlans": [
          {
          "lineItemId": ["ppr.detail.outbound.pack.chuting.medium"],
          "type": ["BaseUnitCount"],
          "values": [2]
          },
          {
          "lineItemId": ["ppr.detail.outbound.pack.chuting.medium"],
          "type": ["BaseRate"],
          "values": [0.4]
          }
          ],
          "planDates": [1516921200]
          }')
```

where the website is internal and it is a false one just for tries. You do not have access to it, Although I guess you can help me to build up the code likewise :)

3) To me, after running the code, it seems that it worked (I see for instance Status: 200). Here below the response:

```
Response [http://fclm-labor-reporting-service.integ.amazon.com/explorer/index.html]
  Date: 2018-01-29 18:02
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: text/html
  Size: 54.6 kB
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml11-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta name="author" content="Coral"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <title>FCLMLaborReportingService Explorer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://internal-cdn.amazon.com/sentry.amazon.com/public/javascripts/openid.xhr.js"></...
...
```

However, I see, when checking the resulting output in the website, that no modification shows up.

I would appreciate so much whether you could provide your thoughts and help with the code as you'll be certainly wiser than me on this one :D

thanks!

Comment: Maybe you need to specify the `content_type("application/json")`.

Comment: Suggestion: remove the Amazon internal URLs

Answer (score 0):

Most likely problem is the data isn't readable by the server. Ensure you're setting the [correct Content-Type header](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/httr/versions/1.3.1/topics/content_type):

```
POST(
    url = "http://fclm-labor-reporting-service.integ.amazon.com/explorer/index.html",
    config = content_type("application/json"),
    body = ...
)
```

Also worth mentioning that you can automatically turn R data structures into JSON by [adding the `encode` parameter to the POST call](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/httr/versions/1.3.1/topics/POST). You didn't specify where your data came from, but it could save you an extra step. E.g. something like this:

```
the_data <- list(
    warehouseId = c("BNA5"),
    planType = c("OP2"),
    lineItemPlans = data.frame(
        lineItemId = c("ppr.detail.outbound.pack.chuting.medium", "ppr.detail.outbound.pack.chuting.medium"),
        type = c("BaseUnitCount", "BaseRate"),
        values = c(2, 0.4)
    ),
    planDates = c(1516921200)
)
POST(
    url = "http://fclm-labor-reporting-service.integ.amazon.com/explorer/index.html",
    body = the_data,
    encode = "json"
)
```

Comment: I commented on your answer in another answer so that I had enough characters to use. Thanks for your help..

Comment: That’s a redirect to a sign-in page